# Maximal torus, adding a commuting element

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be an algebraic group, and $T$ a maximal torus of $G$.

My definition of a torus is that it is isomorphic to $\Bbb G_m^r$ for some $r\in \Bbb N$. Then, a maximal torus $T$ is one that is not contained in any other torus. I am not sure how that would imply this:

There exist no $g\in G\backslash T$ such that $g$ commutes with all of $T$?

I see in the Lie group setting a maximal torus is maximal along those groups that are compact, connected, abelian (which implies they are isomorphic to $T^n$, which is $\Bbb{G}_m$). I guess in that setting, if we could add $g$ to $T$ without breaking compactness, connectedness, then we would fail to be maximal. I don't even know if that is possible. I'm not in the Lie group setting, so its just a thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP here. This is my attempt self-answer.

Since $T\cong \Bbb G_m \times\dots \times \Bbb G_m$, the latter is commutative, then $T$ is commutative.

Say $T$ is a torus. If $T$ is not maximal, then there is some $T'\supsetneq T$. Then, there is an element $t\in T'\backslash T$, where $t$ commutes with all elements of $T'$, and hence commutes with all elements of $T$.

I.e. If $T$ not maximal, then there is $t\in T'\backslash T$ such that $t$ commutes with all of $T$.

Contrapositve: If there is no $t\in T'\backslash T$ commuting with all of $T$, then $T$ is maximal.

(I think something is still wrong, since that $t$ is still assumed to be in a torus, and not just the whole group)